# How do I use service account in deployed code?

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-iam

I have used the IAMCredentialsClient to generate an access token for the service account on a project

```js
  const client = new IAMCredentialsClient();
  const [token] = await client.generateAccessToken({
    name: 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/my-service-account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
```

this has successfully authenticated as I now have an access token.

I have also used `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account my-service-account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to allow running as a service account locally.

To initialise the API client, locally I can do something like this:

```js
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: '../AppData/Roaming/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json',
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
      });
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
```

This works locally but I plan to containerise this app and then deploy it with Cloud Run. Obviously using keyFile and a file path would not work. How would I write the code in a way that the production code knows to use the service account?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Run has a default service account and a metadata service. You can request access tokens from the metadata service.

In your post, you are impersonating a service account. You can attach any service account you require, assign IAM roles to that service account, and then request access tokens. There is no need to involve impersonation which would require more permissions than are necessary.

By using the default Cloud Run service account (service identity), you do not need to download, manage, protect, or deploy the service account key JSON file. This is a best practice.

Review this guide for more details on Cloud Run's Service Identity:

[Google Cloud Run Service Identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity)

Comment: But how do I use this service account in the code?

Comment: @ChrisA - you specify the service account email address when you deploy the Cloud Run service. The [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#deploying_a_new_service_with_a_user-managed_service_account) I provided shows how to do this in the GUI, CLI and Terraform.

Comment: Yes but how do I _use_ the service account _in the code_?

Comment: You don't. You request access tokens from the metadata service. That is the point of a best practice. You do not directly use the service account.

Comment: Ok so how do I *not* use the service account in the code?

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? Do you know how to use the metadata service? The [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#fetching_identity_and_access_tokens_using_the_metadata_server) I provided shows you how to request an access token.

Comment: This [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/authenticate-workloads#applications) has Python code for fetching an access token from the metadata service.

Comment: I've read the link but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I just need to know how to provide a token for the service account (or metadata service account) in the code instead of needing to pass a file path.

Comment: If you have configured Cloud Run correctly with the desired service account, use this line of code to use the metadata service: `const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth()`. The function will automatically fetch from the metadata service. Note: there are no parameters required to use ADC (Application Default Credentials). That is a very important concept to master when working with Google Cloud.

Comment: Ahhh, that was what I needed to know...we got there eventually! Thank you

Comment: You might need to do this because of the sheets scope: `const auth = new GoogleAuth({scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'});`

Comment: Considering it's such an important concept, there doesn't really seem to be any documentation explaining that the auth credentials will automatically be fetched...

Comment: Study Application Default Credentials. That is a process of finding credentials. When running in a compute service, the SDK will fetch credentials from the metadata service. When running on your development computer, it will fetch credentials from the CLI setup. There are more options. Start with the basics of development on Google Cloud. There are lots of features to make your development job easier. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials